# C++ Armadillo, error: Parameter 3 to routine DGEBAL was incorrect

Tags: c++, lapack, armadillo

I am using C++ armadillo library to do some statistical computation involving matrices. What the computation does is trying to find a best model with different parameterizations by looping through all the possible combinations of the parameter values.

However, I am getting random error: Parameter 3 to routine DGEBAL was incorrect, where DGEBAL seems to be a lapack routine. If I pick the parameter combination that causes the error and re-run a single computation with that parameter combination, everything is OK.

So, I am confused. Does anyone know what was wrong? Is it because the lapack library I am using is too old? Thanks.

Comment: What's the version of lapack you use ?